# Partitioning a circular buffer while keeping order

Tags: algorithm

I've got a circular buffer with positive natural values, e.g.

```
  1  5
4      2
11     7
  2  9
```

We're going to partition it into exactly two continuous parts, while keeping this order. These two parts in this example could be:

- `(4  1  5)`  and  `(2  7  9  2  11)`,
- `(7  9  2  11  4)` and `(1 5 2)`,
- etc.

The idea is to keep order and take two continuous subsequences.

And the problem now is to partition it so that the sums of these subsequences are closes to each other, **i.e. the difference between the sums must be closest to zero**.

In this case, I believe the solution would be: `(2 7 9 2)` and `(11 4 1 5)` with sums, respectively, `20` and `21`.

How to do this optimally?

Comment: optimally in the sense of computational cost or just optimal solution?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak computational cost. We can find an optimal solution in quadratic time using naïve approach, right? :)

Comment: Should be linear - see Dukelings's post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algorithm:

1. Calculate the total sum.
2. Let the current sum = 0.
3. Start off with 2 pointers at any point (both starting off at the same point).
4. Increase the second pointer, adding the number it passed, until the current sum is more than half of the total sum.
5. Increase the first pointer, subtracting the number it passed, until the current sum is less than half of the total sum.
6. Stop if either:

   - The first pointer is back where it started, or
   - The best sum is 0.5 or 0 from half the total sum (in which case the difference will be 1 or 0).

     The difference can be 1 only if the total sum is odd, in which case the difference can never be 0. (Thanks Artur!)
7. Otherwise repeat from step 3.

Check all the current sums we got in this process and keep the one that's closest to half, along with indices of the partition that got that sum.

**Running time:**

The running time will be `O(n)`, since we only ever increase the pointers and the first one only goes around once, and the second one can't go around more than twice.

**Example:**

Input:

```
  1  5
4      2
11     7
  2  9
```

Total sum = 41.

Half of sum = 20.5.

So, let's say we start off at 1. (I just put it on a straight line to make it easier to draw)

```
p1, p2
V
 1  5  2  7  9  2  11  4
```

sum = 0

```
p1 p2
V  V
 1  5  2  7  9  2  11  4
```

sum = 1

```
p1    p2
V     V
 1  5  2  7  9  2  11  4
```

sum = 6

```
p1       p2
V        V
 1  5  2  7  9  2  11  4
```

sum = 8

```
p1          p2
V           V
 1  5  2  7  9  2  11  4
```

sum = 15

```
p1             p2
V              V
 1  5  2  7  9  2  11  4
```

sum = 24

```
   p1          p2
   V           V
 1  5  2  7  9  2  11  4
```

sum = 23

```
      p1       p2
      V        V
 1  5  2  7  9  2  11  4
```

sum = 18

```
      p1          p2
      V           V
 1  5  2  7  9  2  11  4
```

sum = 20

Here the sum (20) is 0.5 from half the total sum (20.5), so we can stop.

The above corresponds to `(11 4 1 5) (2 7 9 2)`, with a difference in sums of `1`.

Comment: +1 The only improvement I can think of is to stop the algorithm when the difference is zero (in case total sum is even) or one if (in case total sum is odd).